# Access to ElementById from different javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In javascript file `inClockingModels.js` i have this function:

```
Modal.prototype.SetText = function(text, tipkovnicaModal) {
    this.textElement.innerHTML = text + '<img id="tipkovnicaModalSlika" src = "' + tipkovnicaModal + '" alt ="Modalna tipkovnica" height="100" width="100" />';
}
```

I want to get img `id="tipkovnicaModalSlika"`in other javascript file `inClocking.js`. I tried with this one but its not working:

```
document.getElementById('tipkovnicaModalSlika').addEventListener('click', ShowKeyboardMain);
```

How can I access to `getElementById()` from one javascript file to the other?

Comment: What you have used should (and does) work fine. You just need to ensure that you add the event listener *after* you insert the element with that `id` in to the DOM. I'm assuming you're currently attempting to do it before the element exists, hence no event handler is bound, or you get a 'cannot call function on null' error

Comment: You were right, that was a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as JavaScript running in a browser doesn't care what file other scripts are in, as they execute on a context, normally the `window` of the browser. What is important is the order in which they are evaluated.

You may need to wait for the window to have loaded before trying to add an event handler. Or you might have to wait until the dynamic element has been created.

If you are unsure when the dynamic element will become available, I suggest looking into event delegation, where you can add a handler to a parent element you know is ready to listen for events on its children via bubbling. If you are using jQuery this is extremely simple.

It is mentioned in the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/on/